# move_base stop navigation

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the navigation stack with Trajectory Planner and dwa enabled. I am looking for a straightforward way to stop my robot during its navigation (for emergency or safety reason for example). One way to do this is to send the current robot position as a goal, but I am wondering if a stop navigation service already exists. I found the topic /move_base/cancel, but it is a request to cancel a specific goal.
Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46214/move_base-stop-navigation/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-11**:
@rastaxe did you ever tested to stop the robot posting its actual position as goal?? if so how did you do it?

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2014-10-02**:
sorry for the late response, but I found only now this comment. Yes, actually I use the current position of the robot as a goal, to stop it in a reactive way. It is straightforward, with amcl you can read the amcl_pose topic and sends this pose as goal with actionlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use [actionlib](http://ros.org/wiki/actionlib) to send goals to your robot as shown in [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals). The action client provides the method [cancelGoal](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html#ab267cd5f2e3bb0e180a91b2bf1666ef5). When you call it, the robot should stop moving.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-15**:
@Lorenz how should i call the cancelGoal ? In the same node as in the tutorial? Im working on a person detecting code so the idea is that when a person is detected to stop the robot. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks